# JPA violating foreign key constraint

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

(Original question edited based on further tests)

Essential details:

```
Table Environment
    PK NUMBER,
    Name CHAR(3)

Table ApplicationEntity
    PK NUMBER,
    Name VARCHAR2(64)

Table ApplicationInstance
    PK NUMBER,
    ApplicationEntityFk NUMBER references ApplicationEntity(PK),
    EnvironmentFk NUMBER references Environment(PK)
```

The JPA provider is EclipseLink.

An `ApplicationInstance` is one instance of an `ApplicationEntity("MyApp")`
deployed to a specific `Environment ("DEV","UAT","PRD")`. A single `ApplicationEntity` may have an `ApplicationInstance` deployed to each `Environment`.

```
class Environment
{
    private Long PK;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name="PK")
    public Long getId()
    {
        return PK;
    }
    ...
}
class ApplicationInstance
{
    private Environment environment;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="EnvironmentFk")
    Environment getEnvironment()
    {
        return environment;
    }
}
```

If I create an `ApplicationInstance` with a bogus `Environment(PK=100,Name="FOO")`:

With `merge()`: Rather than rejecting the insert because there is no such `Environment`, the `Environment` table is being updated with a new row `(PK=100,Name="FOO)`.

With `persist()` the following exception (edited) is thrown:

`During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: Environment`

Questions:

1. Why are the results different in `persist()` and `merge()`?
2. Are `cascade MERGE` and `DEFAULT` on and off, respectively, by default?
3. Is it an annotation issue?

Comment: How are you caling into JPA?  Are you using merge/persist or what exactly?